# Apple Web App Keeps Going Into New Window

Tags: javascript, html

The first page of my Apple web app opens in a web app but when you press a link to go to another page inside the web app, it opens in Safari. Even though, that page is Apple-Web-App-Capable. 
I have these codes in all of my pages:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white">
```

How can I prevent new links (with web app capabilities on) from opening in Safari.